# How Do I Get PHP To Bring In The Contens Of The File

Tags: php, random, get

I have most of the code here to randomly get an article from a directory and then bring it in and pass it through spintax, then output it to another file, but it will not work.

```
<?PHP
   class Spintax {
      public function process( $text ) {
        return preg_replace_callback(
           '/\{(((?>[^\{\}]+)|(?R))*)\}/x',
           array($this, 'replace'),
           $text
        );
      }

      public function replace( $text ) {
        $text = $this->process( $text[1] );
        $parts = explode('|', $text );
        return $parts[ array_rand( $parts ) ];
      }
   }
?>

<?PHP
   ob_start();
   $files = glob("spintax_articles/*.txt");
   $spintax = new Spintax();
   $string = 'THIS NEEDS TO BE THE RANDOM ARTICLE CONTENT FROM $FILES';
   echo $spintax->process( $string );
   $page = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_flush();
   $fp = fopen("./article_output.txt", "w");
   fwrite( $fp, $page );
   fclose( $fp );
?>
```

Where I have this "THIS NEEDS TO BE THE RANDOM ARTICLE CONTENT FROM $FILES" I don't know what to put there to actually bring in the contents of the article. It should be the entire contents of the text file so it can be passed through the spintax and then saved out. What would I need there to make this function correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = file_get_contents($files[rand(1, count($files)) -1]);
```

Why do you `echo` the result of `$spintax->process($string)` only to grab it back with `ob_get_contents()`? You could simply associate it to another variable, or put it directly in the `fwrite()`.

Comment: I added that $string line you suggested and it did not work. I got this error: Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty The reason I had the echo in was I was testing it out via a batch file and looking at it on the screen is all.

Comment: Thats probably because `$files` is empty, probably because `glob()` failed, probably because there is no file matching `"spintax_articles/*.txt"`.

Comment: Thank you Havenard, it works fine now. I needed "C:\the\full\path\to\spintax_articles\*.txt" put in then it worked just fine. Thank you very much!